# Lwc components are visible on record page but in flexiPage.xml it is not there

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, deployment, package.xml, flexipages

Lwc components are visible on record page but in flexiPage.xml it is not there.

1. I have updated the package.xml to latest 51 version but issue is still there.
2. When I add an aura component, it reflects in the .xml file after retrieval but when I add lwc, no changes are there in .xml of flexi page.